# PHP replace the data inside HTML table tags

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to replace a part of a string with another but the part im trying to replace has table HTML tags.

```
$string1 = "&bull; Somethig.
<table border="0"><tbody><tr><td>New Data</td></tr></tbody>/<table>
<br/>Something else;

$string2 = "&bull; Somethig.
<table border="0"><tbody><tr><td>Old Data</td></tr></tbody>/<table>
<br/>Something else;
```

I tried this:

```
 $firstarray = explode("table", $string1);
 $secarray = explode("table", $string2);

 $firstarray
 (
     [0] => something
     [1] => New Data
     [2] => something else
 )


 $secarray
 (
     [0] => something
     [1] => Old Data
     [2] => something else
 )

 $need = $firstarray[1];
 $replace = $secarray[1];


 $result = str_replace($replace, $need, $string2);

 echo $result;    // New Data
```

This works but I can't figure out how I'm going to make **$string2** like this:

```
$string2 = "&bull; Something.
<table border="0"><tbody><tr><td>New Data</td></tr></tbody>/<table>
<br/>Something else;
```

Comment: Can you see that your quoted literals are not correct! Remember you cannot have a `"` inside a double quoted literal unless you escape it. Otherwise it closes the string literal

Comment: Alternatively make the string literal single quoted, then you can use double quotes inside it, or visa versa

Comment: _Small Point_ The code you show does not even compile let alone work!

Comment: Why don't you simply replace the part with str_replace()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I see your strings are supposed to be a valid html. So you can work with them using [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.dom.php).

```php
$string1 = "&bull; Somethig.
<table border='0'><tbody><tr><td>Old Data</td></tr></tbody>/<table>
<br/>Something else;";

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($string1);

$tds = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');

foreach($tds as $td) {
    $td->noveValue = 'New Data';
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Of course, code will depend on complexity of your html, but main idea is here.